Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception. The project was working few days ago. Now, it shows error
How can I resolve this error?
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fading_edge_scrollview-3.0.0/lib/src/fading_edge_scrollview.dart:116:31: Error: The argument type 'PageController?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollController' because 'PageController?' is nullable and 'ScrollController' isn't.
 - 'PageController' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart' ('/C:/Program%20Files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart').
 - 'ScrollController' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart' ('/C:/Program%20Files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart').
      scrollController: child.controller,


Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


If you are using PreloadPageView then this issue is due to an underlying dependency of this package that is fading_edge_scrollview need to be updated to 4.1.1.
So simply in your pubspec.yaml add this

dependency_overrides:
  fading_edge_scrollview: ^4.1.1

